# Scrollmagic: Prevent scrolling of page while in scene

Tags: jquery, scroll, parallax, scrollmagic

I want to use scrollmagic for an effect on my page.
My scrollscene is defined and works.
Now i want the page to stop scroll while the scene is not finished.

I tried to put my scene in a container with `overflow-y: scroll;` but this died't work on firefox well. (I had to click in that section so scroll it.)

So is it possible to disable scrolling of the whole page while my Scene is not finished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe as stopping the scroll, I'm guessing is essentially the viewport contents not changing, while you scroll.
Actually stopping the scroll would mean that the scrollbar wouldn't move, which would be very bad UX design.

What you're looking for is ScrollMagic's setPin method.
Create a container in your page that has the size of the viewport.
Now if you pin it it in your scene it will stay in position for its duration, effectively pausing content change in the viewport.

For more information [read more in the docs](http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/docs/ScrollScene.html#setPin) and definitely check out the [pinning example](http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/examples/basic/simple_pinning.html).